# Drag And Drop in Eclipse RCP app causes screen to flicker

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, drag-and-drop

As you can see in the short demo at [this link](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7704342_2144099_6595529). My Eclipse RCP application flickers while performing a DND operation. This issue is very annoying and I don't seem to get rid of it. I tried updating video drivers and made sure I have enough RAM available. Does anyone ever experienced an issue like this before? anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

When I update a table in background I use something like this to stop flickering:

```
table.setRedraw(false);
// do something
table.setRedraw(true);
```